# Gdb Python API - Most efficient way to get the value of PC?

Tags: python, gdb

I'm looking for a way to get the value of a PC using the Gdb Python API without it also showing where the PC is pointing to. For instance, if the PC is pointing to main, I want to do something like:

```
print(str(gdb.parse_and_eval("$pc")))
```

without it showing  next to the hex value. I know about `set print symbol off`, but since Gdb sees PC as a function pointer it'll always show the symbol it's pointing to.

Keep in mind I'm looking for a simple, efficient way to do this (that means no `split`/`partition`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
gdb.selected_frame().pc()
```